# Div in front of an image that contains text using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using Photoshop I can make this effect. My question is how can I achieve this through CSS?

Thank you.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Did you mean a text container over an image?

Comment: Please add the code which you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a figure tag, and inside place a figure caption element with position absolute, this should be the correct semantic way of doing it.
Depending on your site you'll use ids or clases to target these elements

http://jsfiddle.net/MPB4H/

**html**

```
<figure>
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejI6T.png"/>
    <figcaption>
        Here comes your text
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**Css:**

```
    figure{
        position:relative;
    }
    figcaption{
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        bottom: 65px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
        color: red;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: Hello again and thank you for this. I have a question though. If I set the width to 80% so that the figcaption will not be as same width as the image, it starts from the left and goes to the right 80% of the image. My question is how can it be centered?

Comment: Add "left:10%;" to the css of the figcaption, since you are using the 80% of the whole width, having 10% on the left side will center your image, picture it as if you also have right margin of 10% to make a 100%

Comment: IF it works, please make sure to mark my answer as the correct one, to close it.

Comment: Thank you, I have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="containter>
    <img class="image" src="car.jpg" />
    <div class="text>here goes your text</div>
</div>
```

And here is your CSS:

```
.container { position: relative; }
.containter .image { position: absolute; z-index: 1;}
.containter .text { position: absolute; z-index: 2; left: 0; bottom: 20px; }
```

Ask me if you don'g get why I wrote those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d3Dj/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejI6T.png" />
    <span class="caption">Here goes text and text and text so on.........</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-container{
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.img-container img{
    width:100%;
}
.caption{
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    color:#CF0943;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:40%;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:"Calibri";
    font-size:18px;
    text-indent:80px;
}
```